# is the variable passed as a pointer for some reason?

Tags: python, function, pointers, reference, module

The code I made works, but I want to know why. I accidentally made a mistake in the code, but for some reason it works, why? When I pass `lastkeys` to `move.mov`, shouldn't keys be a new variable? The same with `ent.playerlocation`, shouldn't be `player` in `move.mov` be a new variable? The original variable is changed to the value of the new one when I exit the function. I've tried to recreate this, but haven't been able to.

main.py:

```
import pygame
import move, updatescreen

class entities:
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerlocation = [64,64]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),pygame.RESIZABLE,32)#pygame.FULLSCREEN
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Window')

    ent = entities()
    lastkeys = [0,0,0,0]
    ispaused = 0

    while True:
        move.userevents(lastkeys)
        move.mov(lastkeys, ent.playerlocation)
        updatescreen.gameupdate(screen,ent)
```

move.py:

```
import pygame, sys

def userevents(keys):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                keys[0] = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keys[1] = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                keys[2] = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                keys[3] = 1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                keys[0] = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keys[1] = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                keys[2] = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                keys[3] = 0

def mov(keys,player):
    if keys[0]:
        player[0] -=1
    elif keys[1]:
        player[0] +=1
    if keys[2]:
        player[1] -=1
    elif keys[3]:
        player[1] +=1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) (I understand that this is almost exactly the opposite of what you're asking, but the answers are relevant, and more importantly, every time this question is asked (about 5 times a day) on SO, it generates an incredible amount of disinformation from people who don't know the difference between assignment and mutating objects, or the difference between a name and a variable, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in a mutable object it gets passed in by reference (thus, any modifications you make to it affects the original object).  For example:

```
>>> def change_list(lst):
...   lst[0] = lst[0] * 2
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> change_list(a)
>>> a
[2, 2, 3]
```

So either make a copy of the list before you pass it into the function:

```
>>> def change_list(lst):
...   lst[0] = lst[0] * 2
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> cpy_a = list(a)
>>> change_list(cpy_a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or after it's passed into the function:

```
>>> def change_list(lst):
...   lst_cpy = list(lst)
...   lst_cpy[0] = lst_cpy[0] * 2
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> change_list(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

For a more thorough discussion, please see: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: **All** objects are passed by reference. But with immutable ones, it doesn't matter...

Comment: How do I not pass by reference?

Comment: I still don't get it, if I do bar = 0 and then def foo(bar):bar+=1 then bar is still 0

Comment: Objects aren't passed, _references_ to objects are passed - by value

Comment: @kommihe: Every value is an object.  Objects are always passed by reference.  But there are *immutable* objects that will copy themselves when trying to modify them.  Numbers are immutable, so `bar += 1` changes the *variable* `bar` to hold a *new* immutable number and the original one is not modified (it's immutable!).

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: umm, no. Not even close.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: Python is *not* pass-by-reference unless one redefines that term (sadly, many do) - pass-by-reference implies `def change(x, val): x = val` does something useful (also see ). Some prefer the term [call by object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm), which has the advantage of being unknown and thus not abused for a hundred different semantics. What you call a variable does not hold any object, it holds what Python calls a reference (some prefer the term "name" due to that difference from e.g. C's variables).

Comment: Technically, you are right.  The subtle differences have been discussed a million times already.  It does not make sense to explain all the details over and over again, I was being fuzzy on purpose to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @kommihe in any case, the solution for you is to make a copy of the list either before or after the function call.  You might be tempted to use the `copy` or `deepcopy` functions from the `copy` module, but you should just do `lst_copy = list(some_lst)`

Answer (score 1):

> When I pass `lastkeys` to `move.mov`, shouldn't keys be a new variable?

No, objects are always passed by reference in Python.  If you pass a list to a function, and the function modifies the list, then the modification is visible from the caller side afterwards.